# How to implement Batch insert in JPA and a Custom UUID Identifier

Tags: java, postgresql, spring-boot, hibernate, jpa

So, I am using Springboot with Data-JPA with POSTGRESQL to insert data into tables:

```
@Entity
@Builder
@Data
class Person{
    @Id
    UUID id;
    String name;
}
```

And the repository for that

```
@Repository
interface PersonRepository extends JPARepository<Person, UUID>{}
```

Say we created a List of persons.

```
List<Person> persons = List.of(....)
Lets assume we have 10 persons in the list..
```

Now, when I did personRepository.saveAll(persons);

So I got into these problems:

1. There were 10 insert statements as well as select select statements before insert.
2. I wanted batch insert with size of 5, so I wanted 2 multivalued inserts statements to fire here, but 10 inserts were being fired.

Now, I solved the point 1 with the help of Custom Repository

```
public interface CustomBaseRepository<T, ID extends Serializable> {

    <S extends T> S customInsert(S entity);

    <S extends T> Collection<S> customInsertAll(Collection<S> entities);

    <S extends T> Collection<S> customSaveAllInBatch(Collection<S> entities);
}
```

```
@Transactional
public class CustomBaseRepositoryImpl<T, ID extends Serializable> implements CustomBaseRepository<T, ID> {

    @Autowired
    private final EntityManager entityManager;

    public CustomBaseRepositoryImpl(EntityManager entityManager) {
        this.entityManager = entityManager;
    }


    @Override
    public <S extends T> S customInsert(S entity) {
        entityManager.persist(entity);
        return entity;
    }

    @Override
    public <S extends T> Collection<S> customInsertAll(Collection<S> entities) {
        entities.forEach(entityManager::persist);
        return entities;
    }

    @Override
    <S extends T> Collection<S> customSaveAllInBatch(Collection<S> entities){
       **//TODO(...): HOW TO DO THIS?**
    }

}
```

So I made my custom repository and exposed the EntityManager and m doing a persist, as I know when m saving the 'persons' list, it's all new records.

Now, SELECT before INSERT issue is fixed, but the batch insert issue still persists..

I tried using the personRepository.saveAll(persons) too, it didn't work, i used these commands in the application properties to enable batch as well, but was unable to make it work.

Please help me out on implementing the batch inserts, i.e Insert multiple records in a single insert statement..

I tried using these properties but didn't work:

```
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.jdbc.batch_size
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.jdbc.order_inserts
Also for URL:
reWriteBatchedInserts was enabled.
```

Please help me out..

Answer (score 0):

1. Just modify your Entity to generate entity ids automatically before inserting. And selects will go away. There's no need to make custom repositories for that

```java
@Entity
@Builder
@Data
class Person{
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "uuid") // new line !!!
    @GenericGenerator(name = "uuid", strategy = "uuid2") //new line !!
    UUID id;
    String name;
}
```

2. As for batch inserts, you might want to try this **after** you use my previous suggestion and use vanilla Spring Data repositories

```
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.jdbc.batch_size=10
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.order_inserts=true
```

Comment: 1. But, since I need the person id pre-existing in the java layer for some other computation, I went ahead with that approach, is there any other optimised way to handle the case where you have generate the ID on the java layer and achieve only insert without the SELECT? 

2.  I tried using the 2nd part w.r.t to steps mentioned in 1, I am getting multiple inserts still.

Comment: Hmm. Let me think about it. Also, are you sure, you can't do this other computation after you save persons to database?

Comment: Umm yes, I need to pre-compute the IDs before persisting it.

Comment: Please, tell me, how do you know, that batches are not actually happening?

Comment: I enabled hibernate logs, so I had given a batch size of 2, and was saving 10 persons, so ultimately 5. queries should be fired, right? 
But I saw 10 inserts. I hope I'm doing it right

Comment: Logs might be confusing. I see 10 inserts too. But if I intercept actual queries, I see something like this {"name":"Batch-Insert-Logger", "connection":5, "time":1, "success":true, "type":"Prepared", "batch":true, "querySize":1, "batchSize":4, "query":["insert into persons (name, person_id) values (?, ?)"], "params":[["john4","[B@292109c7"],["john5","[B@ba6907f"],["john6","[B@1d38ca2b"],["john7","[B@6aa909cb"]]}
So it might be 4 different queries, but they go in one batch. Not all databases know syntax with coma separated groups after VALUES